# Difference Equation Question

Tags: matrices

I do not have experience with differential equations, but I'm in a modeling and simulations class which has asked this question.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
r(n) = r(n-1) - r(n-4) - a
```

This is a 4th order difference equation.  How do you turn this into a series of first order linear difference equations, and how can those be transformed into matrix form?  I have spoken with my professor and it still wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a first order relationship that will look like this:

$r_n=pr_{n-1}+q$

Then you will also have: $r_{n-1}=pr_{n-2}+q$ and $r_{n-2}=pr_{n-3}+q$ and $r_{n-3}=pr_{n-4}+q$

A bit of substitution gives:

$r_{n-1}=pr_{n-2}+q=p(pr_{n-3}+q)+q=p(p(pr_{n-4}+q)+q)+q$

$r_{n-1}=p^3r_{n-4}+p^2q+pq+q$

$r_{n-1}-p^2q-pq-q=p^3r_{n-4}$

$r_{n-4}=\frac{r_{n-1}-p^2q-pq-q}{p^3}$

Substituting this into $r_n=r_{n-1}-r_{n-4}-a$ gives us:

$r_n=r_{n-1}-\frac{r_{n-1}-p^2q-pq-q}{p^3}-a$

or

$r_n=(1-\frac1{p^3})r_{n-1}+\frac{p^2q+pq+q}{p^3}-a$

But $r_n=pr_{n-1}+q$

So $(1-\frac1{p^3})=p$ and $\frac{p^2q+pq+q}{p^3}-a=q$